# Angular4.x Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'classlist.js'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

When I remove comment part in polyfills.ts for polyfills to load page in Internet Explore

```js
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
 import 'reflect-metadata';
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
 import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/animation`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
 import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

But if we do build using angular cli. it throws error in console
I did run this command in project "npm install --save classlist.js"

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'classlist.js' in src
 @ ./src/polyfills.ts 36:0-22
 @ multi ./src/polyfills.ts
```

Please suggest solution

Answer (score 39, accepted):

remove the current package,

```
npm uninstall classlist.js --save
```

then run

```
npm cache verify
```

afterwards run

```
npm install classlist.js --save-exact
```

Comment: Tried this but unfortunately no luck

Answer (score 7):

You're importing a polyfill that is not included by default. You have to install it as a dependency first. How to do that is in a comment on the same line that imports it:

```
// Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
```

The same goes for the `web-animations-js` polyfill if you haven't done so already.

Comment: I did both commands. but still it not working. If I comment line classlist.js, build not failing

Answer (score 0):

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
         import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
         import 'core-js/es6/object';
         import 'core-js/es6/function';
         import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
         import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
         import 'core-js/es6/number';
         import 'core-js/es6/math';
         import 'core-js/es6/string';
         import 'core-js/es6/date';
         import 'core-js/es6/array';
         import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
         import 'core-js/es6/map';
         import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
         import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Answer (score -1):

Run the following commands in terminal/command prompt:

1. `npm install --save classlist.js`
2. `npm install --save web-animations-js`