# Angular - Error: Can't resolve 'classlist.js'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
 import 'classlist.js';
```

I build the project using angular cli it throws an error in console.

Executed this command in project "`npm install --save classlist.js`"

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'classlist.js' in src
@ ./src/polyfills.ts 36:0-22
@ multi ./src/polyfills.ts
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular4.x Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'classlist.js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688818/angular4-x-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-classlist-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily solve that with the following commands:

```
npm uninstall classlist.js --save
npm cache verify
npm install classlist.js --save-exact
```